# Spring Request Mapping - Mapping all GET requests in a unique endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, request-mapping

As the title says I need a method to map all GET requests in a unique endpoint.

For example if I make n different requests like these (appending a slash for each request):

1. `http://localhost:8080/test`
2. `http://localhost:8080/test/2`
3. `http://localhost:8080/test/2/3`
4. `http://localhost:8080/test/2/3/4`
   ...

the request should be intercepted and elaborated by the same endpoint.

Currently I solved the problem declaring the following `@RequestMapping`:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = {"*", "*/*", "*/*/*", "*/*/*/*", "*/*/*/*/*", "*/*/*/*/*/*"})
public ResponseEntity<?> get(RequestEntity<?> request) throws IOException {
    // code
}
```

and it works.

But I don't like that syntax, I think it's messed and looking at the code the scope here is a little bit complex to understand. After that, theoretically, I can accept an "infinite number" of `/` so I should declare a very big amount of mappings (composed using the `*/` sequence) in the value of `@RequestMapping`.

Someone knows a cleaner way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = {"/**"})
```

Comment: Ohh yes, I tried it and it works like a charm. The simplest way is always the better way. Thank you for your effort and for your fast response.

Comment: Or simpler: `@GetMapping("/**")` (Spring Framework 4.3+ / Spring Boot 1.4+)

Comment: @Andreas Yeah, thank you... anyway I'm using the extended annotation cause I support HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE and other types too.